# How to implement previews on windows using visual studio and MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, window, preview

We have our proprietary file format. Visual studio MFC desktop application (native C++ mostly) renders it on screen. 
How to implement preview for the file. By preview I mean the preview that we get in explorer (e.g. for word or bmp files)
Which interface needs to be implemented?
Any input on where to get started will be useful.

Comment: There is nice MSDN article about that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edak6tf8.aspx

Comment: That article is related to PrintPreview.  I am asking about a preview that would make ( a hint of ) contents  visible in explorer ( without launching the application) . If you still feel that article is helpful , please point to specific part(s) of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By preview I mean the preview that we get in explorer (e.g. for word
>   or bmp files) Which interface needs to be implemented?

From your description, it sounds like you are asking for a [Shell Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx).  In particular, you should investigate the [Thumbnail Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118(v=vs.85).aspx).  It exposes the [IThumnailProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to make it easy to implement a thumbnail handler.

Take a look at [C++ Windows Shell thumbnail handler (CppShellExtThumbnailHandler)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35) for some sample code.